# How to fill combobox having different controllers from database?

Tags: java, database, javafx

I'm having a problem and I don't know how to solve it. I'm building a "food company" and want to write a program to control the items that have been bought/sold, etc.

I have `viewDrinks.fxml`, `jdbcDrinks.java`, `controllerDrinks.java` where I controll the drinks, for adding or deleting them and persisting them in a database.

But now, I have another view called "Sales" where I want to choose from a ComboBox what drink I want to sell. I'm not sure how I should fill this combobox with items that are not in `jdcbSales`, `sales.fxml` and `controllerSales.fxml`.

I been trying differrent approaches but I haven't found a working solution.

On my controllerSales I have:

```
jdbcDrinks databaseObject;

@FXML
private ComboBox drinkField;


public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        ObservableList<String> drinkList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(databaseObject);
        this.drinkField.setItems(drinkList);
        this.drinkField.setEditable(false);
        this.drinkField.getSelectionModel().select(0);

}
```

In jdbcDrinks I have:

```
public void getDrinkName{
ps = conexion.prepareStatement("SELECT name FROM drinks");
rs = ps.executeQuery();
}
```

I want to write a method in jdbcDrinks to get the items from the database, but I'm not sure how to write it and use it on controllerSales.

Comment: Hi Multi. Could you include any code you've attempted to write to get the drinks items from the database? Doesn't have to compile or anything but may help someone provide a solution.

Comment: Dear,

I have posted above what I have tried, but i't dosent work, because I'm not sure how to connect my sales file to the method that I have on jdbcDrinks